# Как продублировать проекты в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, project

Например в "Решении" у меня есть один или несколько проектов. Как выделенные проекты продублировать?

Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слово "продублировать"?

Comment: @Igor, скопировать и вставить (может быть вставить несколько раз).

Answer (score 4):

Вроде, через интерфейс- это сделать нельзя.

Заходите в папку где лежит *.csproj, далее копируете ее целиком, переименовав саму папку и имя *.csproj файла.

Далее, через интерфейс Visual Studio выбираем добавить существующий проект.

Comment: Гуид проекта вроде должен быть уникальным, а при такой копипасте он будет одинаковым и могут быть глюки.